# Does Spring Data JPA require Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to write a small example program with Spring Data JPA.

Is Spring Boot a requirement to use this spring project?

Comment: You should be able to just use spring core and spring data jpa.

Comment: Yes you can, but keep in mind spring-boot do a lot of stuff automatically and without it you have to set it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are perfectly fine to use Spring Data JPA by itself.

Do note that Spring Boot makes it easier to set up a project, all [Spring Data JPA examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa) use:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: OK, 10x for the quick reply

Comment: This is an Spring Boot + JPA example !

Comment: @KarolDowbecki sorry but I saw that if you wrote Boot isn't mandatory and stop. I just think you should explain a bit more, like without Boot no `$ java -jar app.jar` for example. 

At the end you right, I shouldn't have down vote your answer, I clicked to fast . I'm sorry for that. (If you edit your post, I'll be able to upvote it).

Comment: @Karol Yes, I had to create the transaction manager, hibernate properties, etc, but it works fine without spring boot.

Answer (score 4):

After trying, I found it is possible to use Spring Data JPA with plain Spring, without spring boot.

When not using boot, the following are needed:

1) spring-core maven dependency

2) spring-context dependency

3) spring-data-jpa dependency

4) hibernate-entitymanager or some other JPA provider

5) mysql-connector-java or some other DB connector

6) javax.persistence-api dependency

7) AnnotationConfigApplicationContext instead of SpringBootApplication

8) @EnableJpaRepositories("mypackage")

9) @ComponentScan("mypackage")

10) @Bean for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and dataSource

11) Setting Hibernate properties to EntityManager

12) @Bean for PlatformTransactionManager

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring without Boot module but, in your case, you'll have to consider building an project containing Spring Core + Data + JPA and run it inside an Application Server.

If you just do some small example, like you said, Spring Boot + Data + JPA might be faster and easier to setup and run.

Comment: Why would I need an application server? I just want data access to a DB.

Comment: Because Spring Core can't stay up by itself unless it's used inside an AppServer or in conjunction with Spring Boot module.

Comment: I don't want it to stay up. Its an example and just needs to demonstrate accessing the DB.

Comment: You don't need Spring to make an POC of executing an SQL request https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm